# mysql where date is before now + 2 weeks

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

How to get the rows out of a MySQL DB where the field date is before NOW + 2 weeks?

I have tried

```
WHERE date_ready < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

But that is not the rows returning that I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying dates that are before today **minus** two weeks, not **plus**. You should use `date_add` instead of `date_sub`:

```
WHERE date_ready < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
-- Here -----------^
```

Answer (score 2):

Or even, `now()` minus 2 week,

```
where date_ready < (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

with just date

```
where date_ready < (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
WHERE date_ready < DATE_ADD(now(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)
-- Here -----------^
```

and

```
WHERE date_ready < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL + 14 Day)
    -- Here -----------^
```